# fputcsv vs fpassthru в SPL

Tags: php

```
    <?php
    $rates = array(
        array('currency' => 'Australia $', 'rate' => 0.93630),
        array('currency' => 'Canada $', 'rate' => 0.92060),
        array('currency' => 'Euro', 'rate' => 1.35630),
        array('currency' => 'Hong Kong $', 'rate' => 0.12900),
        array('currency' => 'Japan yen', 'rate' => 0.00980),
        array('currency' => 'Swiss franc', 'rate' => 1.11300),
        array('currency' => 'UK sterling', 'rate' => 1.69700)
    );
    if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
        $titles = array_keys($rates[0]); // currency and rate  // вернет все ключи
        $file = new SplTempFileObject(); // указ можно также max memory
        $file->fputcsv($titles);  // записыв currency and rate
        foreach ($rates as $currency){ //массивв
  1          $file->fputcsv($currency); //ложим массив
        }
        $file->rewind(); // перемотать в начало
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Contend-Discription: attachment; filename=rates.csv');
 2       $file->fpassthru();
        //Читает данные из файла с текущей позиции до конца файла и помещает их в буфер выходного потока.
        exit;
    }
    ?>
```

не могу сооброзить разницу между 1 и 2 строкой , они же делают одно и тоже ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> не могу сооброзить разницу между

http://php.net/fpassthru
http://php.net/fputcsv

Comment: т.е. он снач его на серверной стороне делает а потом через fpassthru выкидываает пользователю как сформированный?

Comment: @msim именно так